# Spock testing of spring controllers and repositories

Tags: spring-boot, spock

I have a spring 2.67 app that uses:

```
testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '2.1-groovy-3.0'
testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '2.1-groovy-3.0'
```

I would really like to test the endpoints with their Http response codes and payload.  Many of these controllers have @Service and/or @Autowired repositories.

I have been searching and searching for an example to do these types of integration tests.  But when I try to run a test such as:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class OfficeControllerTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    HardwareRepository hardwareRepository;


    def testSize() {
        def office = new Office(name: "test")
        def hardware = new Hardware(hardwareId: 123, activationDate: LocalDate.now(), officeInternalId: office, osVersion: "iOS");
        assert(hardwareRepository.save(hardware))

        when:
        List<Hardware> hardwareList = hardwareRepository.findAll();

        then:
        assert(hardwareList.size() > 0)
    }
}
```

I get the exception:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

I thought that the ApplicationContext would be loaded so the @Autowired, @Repository (with embedded database), etc would load at test time?

I haven't seen any recent documentation on how to use Spock for these types of tests and I would really appreciate any help in finding it or solving this issue.

Comment: Usually there's a root cause of the exception that shows what really prevented the context from loading. Either look for it yourself or post the full exception stacktrace here.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct, I had a db\changelog\db.changelog-master.yaml under test\resources and src\resources and that prevented liquibase from parsing, which blocked the applicationContext from starting.  

I removed the one under test\resources and now its working.